# Laravel Query Builder hard coded data is not inserted with post method

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I am trying to insert hard coded data with QueryBuilder insertGetId() method.

my code is-

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class StudentController extends Controller
{
    public function addStudent()
    {
        $foreign_key = DB::table('students')->insertGetId([
            'id' => 'stu-000002',
            'name' => 'Ahsan',
            'email' => 'ahsan@example.net',
        ]);

        echo $foreign_key;
    }
}
```

My migration file is-

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

return new class extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('students', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('id', 30)->primary();
            $table->string('name', 100);
            $table->string('email', 100)->unique();
            $table->timestamp('created_at')->useCurrent();
            $table->timestamp('updated_at')->useCurrent();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('students');
    }
};
```

My route is -

```
Route::post('/add-student', [StudentController::class, 'addStudent']);
```

But result is -

```
Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException
The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.
```

But when I try to insert data with get method like-

```
Route::get('/add-student', [StudentController::class, 'addStudent']);
```

Data has been inserted . But primary key has been retrived 0 as primary key is custom string.

How can I solve this problem. Thank you.

Comment: what is the output of  
`        echo $foreign_key;
`  ?

Comment: The second route is the one you should use. The first fails because you're trying to retrieve the page with a get request. What is the value of `$foreign_key`?

Comment: Also please add your migration file in your question .

Comment: @Douwe de Haan, post method should be used for saving data. Data can be retrieved with post method to0 as data has been saved with get method. is there any issue of csr token adding with saving data? This should be confirmed.

Comment: Yes post should be used, but you're using a different request on that url. ` MethodNotAllowedHttpException` means you're not using post. And post method for saving data is correct, but only when you have a form with data you need to send, otherwise you could just use get. So the  `MethodNotAllowedHttpException` means that you should use a different method and the fact that you get `0` back is because of the method you're using ([documentation here](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_insertGetId)). Especially note the `(int)` in front of the method.

Answer (score 1):

run this command in terminal:

```
php artisan route:cache
```

So what this command does is, it registers new routes or gives an error if there is something wrong with your route file.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with what you're doing:

**Problem 1:**

The first is the `MethodNotAllowedException`. I guess you're trying to use a `GET` request on a `POST` URL. This won't work, because Laravel blocks the 'wrong' method.

Use `POST` when you have data to submit (or if you really want to stick to the 'use post when saving'-creed use a form). Use `GET` when you want to access an URL.

**Problem 2**

According to the API ([This one](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_insertGetId)) `insertGetId` returns an integer which is the ID. Since your ID's are strings, you can't use that method.

A solution to that problem would be to change the code like this:

```
public function addStudent()
{
    $student_id = 'stu-000002'

    $insert = DB::table('students')->insert([
        'id' => $student_id,
        'name' => 'Ahsan',
        'email' => 'ahsan@example.net',
    ]);

    if ( ! $insert ) {
        return false;
    }

    echo $student_id;
}
```

The [insert method](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_insert) returns a boolean. Leveraging that you can check whether or not the entry was inserted. If it is, your ID should be good.

Comment: Problem is using get method in route i can insert data. But when I try to insert data using post method in route then the error message- "The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST." is appeared.

Comment: @Solutions That's because your route is specified to use a GET and not a POST. So change the method in your routes file to `Route::post` and it should work.